# Application crashed occasionally when using AKK.Net as the communication channel

Tags: c#, crash, akka.net, helios

we are using AKKA.Net for the communication between several processes.

The version of AKKA.Net we are using is newest: 1.0.7. 
There are about 20 processes which using AKKE.Net. Those processes are windows services.
The communication workload between processes is not heavy, 10 requests/minute, and the workload in night is zero. 
The network is not very stable.
The AKKA.Cluster is not been used in the system.

We add a event handler for  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, so that we have the chance to log some critical exceptions. The code looks like:

```
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, eventArgs) =>
  {
    logger.LogFatal("Unhandled exception captured, Terminating:" + eventArgs.IsTerminating);
  };
```

We keep thoese processes running for several days, and found that some processes (maybe 2 or 3 ) crashed.  We check the log and seems it results from a unexcepted exception of AKKA.Net. The details of the exception is listed as below:

```
Exception message：Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Exception stacktrace：
   at Helios.Reactor.Tcp.TcpProxyReactor.CloseConnection(Exception ex, IConnection remoteHost)
   at Helios.Reactor.Tcp.TcpProxyReactor.ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

The workload at the time when the exception thrown out is almost zero.

Is there any tips on how to fix this issue? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug in Helios that I logged recently](https://github.com/helios-io/helios/issues/77) - working on getting a fix out for it ASAP.

I'll reply back here with a comment once the fix is out, but it's what I've been currently working on this week.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your reply!

Waiting for your good news :)

Comment: Hi, is there any progress on this issues ? :)

Comment: Yep - but still have more work left to go. You'll see why in the release notes. You can also ping me at @aaronontheweb on the Akka.NET Gitter chat or on Twitter.